# Sodium fluoride and varying pH - HF risk

Tags: acid-base, ph, safety, halides

I'm looking into conducting an experiment on the adsorption of fluoride (for my International Baccalaureate Extended Essay). As I will be investigating the role of $\mathrm{pH}$ in adsorption capacity, I will be dealing with $\ce{NaF}$ solutions of varying $\mathrm{pH}$. Could hydrofluoric acid be created by this process, and could it be dangerous in the dilute concentrations I am dealing with (<$0.5\ \mathrm{g\ L^{-1}}$)?

My reasoning is that added $\ce{H+}$ will move the equilibrium of the buffer $\ce{F^{−}(aq) +H3O+(aq) <=> HF(aq) + H2O(l)}$ to the right, and the $\mathrm{pH}$ will hardly change until the buffer capacity is exceeded. I'm still not sure whether this poses  a health risk, though.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51223/can-hydrofluoric-acid-etch-glass-at-a-ph-of-7-0

Comment: (Soluble) fluorides are always poisonous, only the undissociated, relatively non-polar HF (i.e. fluorides under acidic conditions) quickly penetrates the skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  Solutions containing dissolved fluoride salts can form HF under acidic conditions.  I personally would not take any chances with exposure, because even dilute concentrations of HF can cause [severe burns](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/773304-overview) if enough of your skin area is exposed to it.  Standard PPE would include goggles, faceshield and neoprene gloves.  PVC sleeves and lab apron are recommended as well.

Comment: HF does NOT cause visible or even tangible burns *on* the skin, unless highly concentrated, and even then much less than ordinary hydrochloric acid. The effect is one of intoxication of the body parts *below* the affected skin part, followed by systemic intoxication.